# Limit of complex function ${z^2\over |z|}$ as z tends to $z_0$, $z$ not equal to 0.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I have no idea how to find $\lim_{z\to z_0}$ ${z^2\over |z|}$ My text says it should be equal to ${z_0^2\over |z_0|}$ but how does one mathematically prove this?

Comment: Can you use the standard rules of limits or are you looking for a basic $\epsilon-\delta$ proof directly from the definition of a limit?

Comment: Yes I was looking for an epsilon delta proof, just to try and deepen my understanding

Answer (score 3):

One obvious way is to use the fact that the limit of a quotient is the quotient of the limits, as long as the denominator (the limit of) is not 0.

Answer (score 1):

You should check that:

$$\lim_{z \to z_0}\left|\frac{z}{|z|}-\frac{z_0}{|z_0|}\right|=0$$

But:

$$\left|\frac{z}{|z|}-\frac{z_0}{|z_0|}\right|=\left|\frac{z}{|z|}-\frac{z}{|z_0|}+\frac{z}{|z_0|}-\frac{z_0}{|z_0|}\right| \leq \\ \leq \left|\frac{z}{|z|}-\frac{z}{|z_0|}\right|+\left|\frac{z}{|z_0|}-\frac{z_0}{|z_0|}\right|$$

Now:

$$\left|\frac{z}{|z|}-\frac{z}{|z_0|}\right|=|z|\left|\frac{1}{|z|}-\frac{1}{|z_0|}\right|$$

$|z|,|z_0|$ are real number, so you know that $\left|\frac{1}{|z|}-\frac{1}{|z_0|}\right| \to 0$ when $z \to z_0$, $|z| \to |z_0|$, so:

$$|z|\left|\frac{1}{|z|}-\frac{1}{|z_0|}\right| \to 0$$

Next:

$$\left|\frac{z}{|z_0|}-\frac{z_0}{|z_0|}\right|=\left|\frac{z-z_0}{|z_0|}\right| \to 0$$

when $z \to z_0$.